# Custom tasks failing to appear in Custom Tasks Administration in JBPM 7.47.0 despite successful upload: any fixes?

Tags: jbpm

## Need help in JBPM 7.47.0 Issue: Not able to upload Custom Tasks in Custom Tasks Administration :

Error Message: Custom tasks successfully added. The following custom tasks have been skipped as the repository already contains services with the same name as

But the Custom Task does not appear in Custom Tasks Administration, even if we are uploading it the first time. This happened after we uploaded a certain no. of custom tasks and after that, it does not upload any custom tasks. But if we check in the Artifacts section, Jar gets uploaded.

And there are no errors in a log file.

Also let us know if there is a limit on uploading custom tasks and if yes, where it is configured.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.